# Packedbubble having overlapping highCharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use the packed bubble chart, and by design I need the bubbles really big, usually works fine but when I have data with a high values the bubbles start overlapping and having issues. Is there a way to fit all the bubbles and if they do not fit just create scroll?

here the config:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'packedbubble',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Packed Bubble Chart'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        packedbubble: {
            minSize: 20,
            maxSize: 300
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true,
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true,
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            { name: 'A', value: 10 },
            { name: 'B', value: 20 },
            { name: 'B', value: 20 },
            { name: 'B', value: 50 },
            { name: 'B', value: 50 },
            { name: 'B', value: 50 },
        ]
    }]
});
```

Here a [JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/wkjn7u9t/1/)

Thank you!

Comment: I could use maxSize with pixels instead of percentage but still no way to have scroll when they do not fit

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, the zoom feature is not built-in for the packed bubble chart. You can request this feature here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose. The percentage of the size is calculated based on the smaller of the plot width and height, so setting it to 250% will always cause this kind of behavior when there is not enough space. I'm not sure if I entirely understand your use case. Perhaps you could consider using a smaller percentage for the bubbles?

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping. I understand the percentage thing, but even if I use pixels I have the problem if the data has many high values

Comment: @magdalena I saw that the maxSize is related to the height, that's where I have my problem, so usually if the chart is a box with a maxSize: 100% looks perfect. but when you have an horizontal chart, like width: 1000 and height: 400. that maxSize property stays checking only the height, is there a way to fit with the width and take all the space? thank you!

Comment: Basically, the maxSize is calculated based on the smaller dimension, either height or width, using Math.min(plotWidth, plotHeight); it's not specifically based on height alone. You have the option to extend Highcharts and modify the 'getPointRadius' function to suit your needs. For guidance, you might find more information here https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts and base on this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pt6xmbkq/: